# What could be the faster replacement of this sed command?

Tags: perl, unix, sed

I have a script where below sed command works on the input file.

```
 sed -i 's/SESSION_ID/sid/g;s/TIME_HOUR/hh/g;s/TIME_MINUTE/mm/g;s/TIME_SECOND/ss/g;s/TIME_MILLISECOND/mss/g;s/MSISDN/MS/g;s/IMSI/IM/g;s/IMEISV/IV/g;s/name_ALLOCATED_UE_ADDRESS_IPV4/aI4/g;s/IPV6/I6/g;s/OPERATION_TYPE/OT/g;s/LOCATION_AREA_CODE/LC/g;s/CELL_IDENTITY/CI/g;s/RAT_TYPE/RT/g;s/APN/AP/g;s/COUNTRY_CODE/CC/g;s/NETWORK_CODE/NC/g;s/name_SGSN_ADDRESS_IPV4/sI4/g;s/QCI/QC/g;s/SUBSCRIBERGROUP/SG/g;s/MONITORING_KEY/MK/g;s/QUOTA_VOLUME_BIDIRECTIONAL/QV/g;s/MBR_UL/MU/g;s/MBR_DL/MD/g;s/RULE_ID/RD/g;' $FiletosqeezE
```

Now the problem is..it is taking more time than expected to get executed. Could you please advise what could be the faster replacement of this sed command...we can even take the help of perl here.....thanks.

Comment: How _much_ time did you expect it to take? You're unlikely to be able to make it much faster unless you can take advantage of extra info, such as all strings at start of line, for example.

Comment: sorry If I sound dumb...but didn't get your point... specially "such as all strings at start of line, for example." ....thanks for reply BTW...

Comment: give a sample of input so oiptimization could be done. Your sed action list is fast for a generic modification of all those "independant" pattern but maybe not is the are not generic (like many term on 1 line or at the opposite never on same line, ...)

Comment: Post a few lines of representative sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Answer (score 4):

Using a command line perl (joining all the replacements into a single expression):

```
perl -i -pe '
    BEGIN {
      %hash = qw(SESSION_ID sid TIME_HOUR hh TIME_MINUTE mm TIME_SECOND ss TIME_MILLISECOND mss MSISDN MS IMSI IM IMEISV IV name_ALLOCATED_UE_ADDRESS_IPV4 aI4 IPV6 I6 OPERATION_TYPE OT LOCATION_AREA_CODE LC CELL_IDENTITY CI RAT_TYPE RT APN AP COUNTRY_CODE CC NETWORK_CODE NC name_SGSN_ADDRESS_IPV4 sI4 QCI QC SUBSCRIBERGROUP SG MONITORING_KEY MK QUOTA_VOLUME_BIDIRECTIONAL QV MBR_UL MU MBR_DL MD RULE_ID RD);
      $pat = join "|", sort {length($b) <=> length($a)} keys %hash; 
    }
    s/\b($pat)\b/$hash{$1}/g;
  '  $FiletosqeezE
```

**Switches**:

- `-i`: Edit `<>` files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
- `-p`: Creates a `while(<>){...; print}` loop for each “line” in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

Comment: I suppose that's worth a vote, it ran twice as fast as the `sed` option on my 100M test file (albeit with no substitutions).

Answer (score 2):

If you need to be able actually *do* all those replacements on each line, you're unlikely to be able to make it much faster, at least with `sed` itself. Other tools, such as `awk` and `perl`, may give you improvements.

If there's a possibility you can take advantage of *extra* information you may have, there are some ways to make it possibly better.

For example, if you only expect *one* occurrence of each string (such as `SESSION_ID`) on each line, you can get rid of the global flag `g`, which will mean it won't process the rest of the line for each replacement.

Or, if each line only ever contains *one* of the keywords (e.g., no lines with both `SESSION_ID` *and* `TIME_HOUR`, you can use something like `awk` to do the substituting, and use `next` so that the first substitute moves immediately on to the next line rather than checking all the others.

Or, if you know that all keywords are at the start of the line, you can change your substitutes from:

```
s/SESSION_ID/sid/g
```

into:

```
s/^SESSION_ID/sid/
```

which will probably speed things up since it won't have to look beyond the first few characters.

But, without extra information, you *may* get faster performance by creating a hard-coded program for this specific purpose rather than using the more general-purpose `sed` with a script.

With that, you can tweak things like how much data is loaded with each read call and so on. I wouldn't expect *too* much of an improvement since your `sed` strings are fixed rather than regular expressions but it may be worth a shot if you're willing to put in the upfront effort.

---

For what it's worth, that `sed` command breezed through a 100M source file in less than 12 seconds on my box, I don't consider that *too* bad.

Just make sure that, whatever options you test, you test them properly. *Measure, don't guess!*

Answer (score 1):

According to the famous sed one-liner text: 
http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt

If you modify your substitutions like this:

```
sed 's/something/changed/g;s/another/one/g'
```

to

```
sed '/something/ s//changed/g; /another/ s//one/g'
```

you get improvement, i tested it on a small file and the sys portion was halved:

```
(precise)cronkilla@localhost:/tmp$ time sed 's/dog/cat/g;s/fox/horse/g;s/quick/slow/g;s/the/blah/g' n4.txt > n6.txt

real    0m0.043s
user    0m0.039s
sys 0m0.004s


(precise)cronkilla@localhost:/tmp$ time sed '/dog/ s//cat/g;/fox/ s//horse/g;/quick/ s//slow/g;/the/ s//blah/g' n4.txt > n6.txt
real    0m0.052s
user    0m0.050s
sys 0m0.002s
```

Comment: I wonder why that is so? Why does the implementation not optimize this away?

Comment: I don't know I haven't looked at the sed source code, but it does seem like there is room for optimizations.

Comment: Your sys time being halved is neither statistically significant or useful, BTW. CPU time is user+sys and that goes from 43 in the original to 52 in your version. However, as stated, a sample size of one is pretty much useless for drawing conclusions.

Comment: The sample size was 10000 lines of the same "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog". According to the online documentation sys output is (iii) the system CPU time (the sum of the tms_stime and tms_cstime values in a struct tms as returned by times(2)).